# How to make multiple stacked charts to share the same yAxis?

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have 2 charts with different data, stacked on top of each other. How do I make those 2 charts share the same scale of 1 y-axis?

I configured the y-Axis as follow:

```
yAxes: [{
    display: true,
    stacked: true,
    type: "linear",
    scaleLabel: {
      display: true,
      labelString: "Amount in USD"
    },
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      max: 150000,
      callback: function(label, index, labels) {

        return label / 1000 + "k";

      }
    }
  }]
```

And the data set as follow:

```
labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
backgroundColor: "#FFE0B2",
datasets: [{
  label: "Amount of Sales - YTD",
  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104920, 87461, 22700, 0, 0],
  backgroundColor: [
    "#FFE0B2"
  ],
  borderColor: [
    "#FF9800"
  ],
  borderWidth: 1,
  pointBackgroundColor: "#FFE0B2",
  pointBorderColor: "#FF9800",
  pointBorderWidth: 2
}, {
  label: "Amount of Commission - YTD",
  data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1896, 4373, 1135, 0, 0],
  backgroundColor: [
    "#F8BBD0"
  ],
  borderColor: [
    "#E91E63"
  ],
  borderWidth: 1,
  pointBackgroundColor: "#F8BBD0",
  pointBorderColor: "#E91E63",
  pointBorderWidth: 2
}]
```

Please have a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/pyzaq4j3/

As you can see, in August, the point (orange) is set at ~100k, which is correct.

However, the point (pink) has the value of only ~1.8k, and the point is almost at ~100k, according to the graph.

**Question**: How do I set it so that the pink graph shares the same y-axis as the orange graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line in the y-axis:

```
stacked: true,
```

If you'll remove it, it won't stack the values together.
However, since you specified `backgroundColor` on your datasets, and the first dataset is **"Amount of Sales - YTD"** which has higher values, it will block the visual of your second dataset.

Comment: If your 2 datasets' values are too distant/apart from each other *(like in your example)*, you might consider using a scale factor on either dataset, use multiple y-axes, or use a different chart component which support **Scale Breaks** (like DevExtreme or canvasJS).